# negation lambda expression in c#, NOT starWith

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list of objects, and i need to filter that objects that one of his properties DONT start with some letter, i see that i can do it:

```
onelist=mylist.where(x=>x.Cod.startwith("A"));
```

but what i need is just the contrary, something like:

> onelist=mylist.where(x=>x.Cod.NOTstartwith("A"));

I dont know if it´s posible, if that it´s not posible i seem to remember that there was a way to in one lamda expression negate other, is correct??

Thanks

Comment: )) It's easy. Use **!**.  `(!x.Cod.StartsWith("A"));` or `(x.Cod.StartsWith("A") == false);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use standard boolean operator:

```
onelist = mylist.Where(x => !x.Cod.StartsWith("A"));
```

Comment: ohh i am stupid i probe to put the boolean operator in a few sites but not there. 

Thanks a lot
Gracias